How to expand argument in the Expl3 command \str_if_eq?
Is it possible to write the following macro \checkparen without using a variable?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkparen}{m}
{
  \str_set:Nx \l_f_str {\str_head:n {#1}}
  \str_if_eq:NNTF {\l_f_str} { ( } {\str_range:nnn {#1} {2} {-2}} {#1}
}
    
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


% Example usage
\checkparen{(hello)}

\checkparen{world}


\end{document}


\str_if_eq:NNTF is the wrong function to use here because N absorbs a single token - not a delimited argument. So you shouldn't use e.g. {\l_tmpa_str} but \l_tmpa_str.
Fortunately, \str_if_eq:nnTF and \str_if_eq:eeTF are also available, so you just need to pick the onewhich expands its arguments.
Note that x type expansion is (largely?) deprecated and should be replaced by e. xparse is not necessary on moderately recent kernels.
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkparen}{m}
{% thanks to Skillmon (see comment)
  \str_if_eq:eeTF {\str_head:n {#1}} { ( } {\str_range:nnn {#1} {2} {-2}} {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\checkparen{(hello)}

\checkparen{world}

\end{document}


You can use \str_if_eq:eeTF without creating a new variant (and potentially with a performance gain, since one can use a low-level optimisation with that, I'm not sure whether current expl3 uses that, since there was some policy change a while ago though).

@Skillmon No problem with \st_if_eq:eeTF

@cfr Other than some low-level internal stuff, we don't see the need for x-type expansion any more, so yes it's deprecated but will never be removed or error

@Skillmon because it isn't creating a variant? is that always true? intuitively, it seems like twice the expansion would not be faster than once?

@JosephWright sorry. what did I get wrong?

@cfr Nothing: you put 'Note that x type expansion is (largely?) deprecated', so I was just confirming

@cfr the low level optimisation is that for \str_if_eq:nnTF you need to actually use \exp_not:n on your arguments since the used primitive does an e-type expansion, so if you use \str_if_eq:eeTF you can directly use the primitive instead without \exp_not:n or \tl_to_str:n which is faster. If you generate a variant from \str_if_eq:nnTF what you end up with is something like e-expand then protect from e-expansion.

@Skillmon thanks.

To check the first token in an argument you can also use one of the \tl_if_head... tests (note that there are a few behavioural differences with this, but it should be fine for normal category codes and escape character):
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkparen}{m}
  { \tl_if_head_eq_charcode:nNTF {#1} ( {\str_range:nnn {#1} {2} {-2}} {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% Example usage
\checkparen{(hello)}

\checkparen{world}
\end{document}

